# Spark cache inefficiency

Tags: caching, apache-spark

I have quite powerful cluster with 3 nodes each 24 cores and 96gb RAM = 288gb total. I try to load 100gb of tsv files into Spark cache and do series of simple computation over data, like sum(col20) by col2-col4 combinations. I think it's clear scenario for cache usage.

But during Spark execution I found out that cache NEVER load 100% of data  despite plenty of RAM space. After 1 hour of execution I have 70% of partitions in cache and 75gb cache usage out of 170gb available. It's looks like Spark somehow limit number of blocks/partitions it adds to cache instead to add all at very first action and have a great performance from very beginning.

I use MEMORY_ONLY_SER / Kryo ( cache size appr. 110% of on-disk data size )

Does someone have similar experience or know some Spark configs / environment conditions that could cause this caching behaviour ?

Comment: How are you submitting your job?

Comment: You mean whether I run this job via spark-submit ? Yes, I am.
By the way, now I decrease split size from 400mb to 200mb ( that increase # of Partitions from 250 to 500 ) and this improve "caching ratio"  significantly (  to 80% after first  action in a loop finished ) . But still, why not 100% ?))

Comment: No, what is your spark-submit line?

Comment: spark-submit --class co.comp.explore.EventsGroupByTwoFields --master spark://hadoop.namenode:7077 --name testJoin --num-executors 11 --driver-memory 22g  --executor-memory 22g --executor-cores 6 /path/to/jar/jarName.jar --inputPath hdfs://hadoop.namenode/res/Events_20150707/*/ --outputPathPrefix /path/to/local/out/folder/Events_2D_

Answer (score 0):

So, "problem" was solved with further reducing of split size. With ***mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize*** set to 100mb I got 98% cache load after 1st action finished, and 100% at 2nd action.

Other thing that **worsened** my results was ***spark.speculation=true*** - I try to avoid long-running tasks with that, but speculation management creates big performance overhead, and is useless for my case. So, just left default value for ***spark.speculation*** ( false )

My performance comparison for 20 queries are as following:
- without cache - 160 minutes ( 20 times x 8 min, reload each time 100gb from disk to memory )
- cache - 33 minutes total - 10m to load cache 100% ( during first 2 queries ) and 18 queries x 1.5 minutes each ( from in-memory Kryo-serialized cache )